# Is there a general formalism for 3-variable quadratic diophantine equations without mixed terms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider a polynomial equation
$$P_x(x) + P_y(y) + P_z(z) = 0\tag1 $$

Where $P_x, P_y, P_z$ are polynomials of degree at most two with integer coefficients.

The problem is to characterize all integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $(1)$.

By "characterize" I mean to find some expressions in $n$ integer parameters to use as $(x,y,z)$, perhaps with restrictions on those integer parameters; or to be able to say that there is some finite set of solutions; or to say no solutions exist.

For example, the polynomials $P_x(x) = x^2$, $p_y(y) = y^2$, $P_z(z) = -z^2$ is the familiar Pythagorean equation and has a three-parameter family of solutions 
$$x = 2krs, y = k(r^2-s^2), z = k(r^2+s^2)$$ with $\gcd(r,s)=1$ and one of $r,s$ even; it also has one-parameter families $x = k, y= 0, z = \pm k$, and of course by symmetry it has solutions switching $x$ and $y$.

Without loss of generality, we can restrict the form of our polynomials to contain no linear terms (since we could always shift a variable and perhaps scale by two to get another equation without the linear term) and require that only one constant term appears. Thus I am asking:

> Given, 
>   $$ c_x x^2 + c_y y^2 + c_z z^2 = c_0 \tag2$$
>   is there any general formalism for attacking $(2)$ ?

For specific $(c_x, c_y, c_z, c_0)$ it is usually possible by clever manipulations to solve the problem.  Pell's equation, for example, is a special case (with $c_x = c_0 = 1$ and $c_z = 0$).

But is there a general methodology, and do any of these equations $(2)$ have only one or a finite number of solutions?

Comment: In order to minimize the Pell equation we have to solve a more General equation, at least:  $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+jz^2=c_0$$ This is to ensure that if this quadratic form is not limited to the Pell equation is equivalent to the quadratic form can be reduced to it.  While the formula itself seems cumbersome.   I don't think if there is a point here to draw - because still remove.

Comment: For your first question, you ask, _"...characterize **all** integer triplets ... By characterize I mean to find some expressions in $n$  integer parameters to use as $x,y,z$._" As a short answer, there is **no general formula** for $k>2$, of $$c_1x_1^2+c_2x_2^2+\dots+c_kx_k^2 = 0$$ for general $c_k$ similar to the neat Pythagorean formula that you used as analogy. All one can do is find formulas for **special** cases of $c_k$, like the Pythagorean.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about the integral automorphism group of an indefinite (ternary) quadratic form. Suppose we take $A,B,C> 0$ and ask about
$$ A x^2 - B y^2 - C z^2.  $$ 
We therefore have a symmetric matrix
$$ M =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -B & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -C
\end{array}
\right).
 $$ 
A member of the (proper) automorphism group is a three by three matrix of integers $P$ such that 
$$ \color{magenta}{ P^T M P = M}.   $$

Next, taking $(x,y,z)$ as a row vector and $(x,y,z)^T$ as a column vector, we have the value of the quadratic form as 
$$  (x,y,z) M (x,y,z)^T  $$

So, here is the thing. When $P^T M P = M,$ then
$$ (P^T (x,y,z)) \; M (P (x,y,z)^T)   $$
comes out the same.

And the integral automorphism group is infinite, and typically quite messy to work out in full detail.

It is a theorem of C.L. Siegel that the set of solutions to $Ax^2 - B y^2 - C z^2 = F$ occur in a finite number of distinct orbits under the action of the automorphism group.

Meanwhile, there are usually two infinite subgroups that are easier to deal with. If $AB$ is not a perfect square, then $Ax^2 - B y^2$ has its own infinite automorphism group, which alters $(x,y)$ but leaves $z$ alone. If $AC$ is not a perfect square, then $Ax^2 - C z^2$ has its own infinite automorphism group, which alters $(x,z)$ but leaves $y$ alone.

If you think it, ummm, unattractive, that the full group should not have a parametrization, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141284/integral-orthogonal-group-for-indefinite-ternary-quadratic-form

Answer (score 1):

If $c_x, c_y, c_z, c_0$ all have the same sign, there are only finitely many solutions, which satisfy $|x| \le \sqrt{c_0/c_x}$ etc. (so a search will find them).

If $c_x, c_y, c_z $ have one sign and $c_0$ has the opposite sign, there are no solutions.

Since the set of solutions is invariant under sign changes, the only cases where there is a unique solution are those where the only solution is $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Yes, but I still want to know if there is a general way, when there might be a family of solutions, to determine how to parameterize that family.

Answer (score 1):

Given an initial solution $u,v,w$ to,

$$au^2+bv^2+cw^2 = d$$

then an infinite more can be found using the identity,

$$a x_1^2 + b x_2^2 + c x_3^2 = d(x^2+bcy^2)^2\tag1$$

where,

$$\begin{aligned}
x_1\,&=u x^2 + b c u y^2\\
x_2\,&=v x^2 - 2c w x y - b c v y^2\\ 
x_3\,&=w x^2 + 2b v x y - b c w y^2
\end{aligned}$$

provided you choose $x,y$ such that,

$$x^2+bcy^2 =\pm 1\tag2$$

Thus, if the product of any two of $a,b,c$ is negative, then re-label so you can use the *Pell equation* $(2)$.

Comment: yes, but not all solutions

Comment: @WillJagy. True. But in my work with equal sums of like powers (especially for higher powers), I usually find an _infinite_ number of solutions is enough. Then again, some may want _all_ ... :)

Comment: It's a tossup. Often they ask for all solutions but have no idea how deep is the water they are looking at. If, as does happen, they give an alphabet soup and nothing can be said that comes close to a solution, i mostly vote to close.